# get_posts - get all posts by author id

Tags: get-posts

I want to get all posts by certain author id (current user). Later, I want to pick the first post made by this user (ASC).
I guess I do not use the right arguments in get_posts, am I? $current_user_posts 
always contains an Array with all blog posts in multiple different WP_Post Objects.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();                      

$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $current_user->ID, // I could also use $user_ID, right?
    'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
    'order'         =>  'ASC' 
    );

// get his posts 'ASC'
$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: get_currentuserinfo() is deprecated since version 4.5.0. Replace with: `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm a bit confused. If you want to get onlya element from the posts array you can get it like this:

- reset($current_user_posts) - first post
- end($current_user_posts) - lat post

But if you want to get just one post with the `get_posts()` you can use the `posts_per_page` argument to limit the results.

```
$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $current_user->ID,
    'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
    'order'         =>  'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
    );
```

More info about parameters you can get on [WP Query Class Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page (`get_posts()` takes same parameters as WP Query).

Comment: your $args work fine but I don't get your first answer. How to use $current_user_posts. Could you show me?

Comment: If you want to print the title of the first post you should use: `echo $current_user_posts[0]['title']`. The 'title' is the key for what you need from array. The full list of keys you cang get with `print_r(array_keys($current_user_posts))`.

"How to use" it depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: get the author's first post's id

Comment: You can get the id with: $current_user_posts[0]['ID']

Comment: @kindo, did it helped? Is this the answer you needed?

Comment: $current_user_posts[0]['ID'] does not work. but the first solution with adding 'numberposts' or 'posts_per_page' (used equal) works fine. ty

Comment: @kindo, Sorry, forgot that `get_posts()` returns array of post objects. Use `$current_user_posts[0]->ID`

Comment: The last solution now also works.

Answer (score 9):

```
global $current_user;                     

$args = array(
  'author'        =>  $current_user->ID, 
  'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
  'order'         =>  'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => -1 // no limit
);


$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
$total = count($current_user_posts);
```

and just loop the current user posts

Comment: Can you also explain what the above code does in addtion to posting the code, it will be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 4):

its work by (wp4.9.7)

```
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 $args=array(
 'post_type' => 'POSTTYPE',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
 'author' => $user_id
  );

$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
$total = count($current_user_posts);
wp_die( '<pre>' .  $total . '</pre>' );
```